# Serializing object in flatbuffers in cpp

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

I am attempting to use flatbuffers as a way to communicate between master/slave servers. The issue I am facing is, that after I have read data from `char*` into flatbuffer, I can't find a way to write it back into `char*`. First configuration:

```
flatc --cpp --gen-mutable --gen-object-api -o ${OUT} ${IN}
```

And here is code which bothers me:

```cpp
char* buffer = <MY_FLATBUFFER_DATA>;
auto managedObject = GetMutableManagedObject(buffer);
makeChanges(managedObject);
char* newBuffer = managedObject.deserialize(); // This is my imaginative method
```

I want to be able to deserialize object which has been modified and send it back to the slave. Is it possible? Or I have to use "slower" (as it describes tutorial) `Pack`/`UnPack` methods?

(I do not mind another approach kind of answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need Pack/UnPack. --gen-mutable only allows very limited modification (some scalars), if you want to be able to modify everything you need the object api.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Well, gotta work with what we have ;p